# Javascript text from file utf-8 encoding does not work. But used as hard coded string works perfectly fine

Tags: javascript, string, file, encoding, utf-8

Okay, so I have a bunch of files which look like this:

> Wednesday, August 26 2015, 2:01 PM\u000AOn Mississippi’s Gulf Coast, what was lost and gained from Katrina’s fury\u000ABy DeNeen L. Brown,\u000A\u000A\u000A\u000A\u000A\u000AJabin Botsford\u000A\u000AThe Washington Post\u000A\u000AABOVE LEFT: A fireplace is seen on an empty lot in Long Beach, Miss.

I get the string with ajax and want to print them to console/ html:

```
      $.ajax({
        url: dir,
        success: function(text){
          document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = text;
          console.log(text);
        }
      });
```

But the utf-8 characters (\u00A) do not get encoded (is that the right word?). The text on my website looks exactly like the text above. But when I copy this text and set it as javascript variable

```
var text = 'Wednesday, August 26 2015, 2:01 PM\u000AOn...';
```

and print it to console or as html text I get perfectly well formatted text. How can I print my file to my website with spaces and linebreaks?

Comment: set `contentType` in your ajax to `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",`

Comment: @Maverick: Nope, that didn't work